# Rust: moving value out of option and pushing onto a stack

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a value of type Option. If there is a Leg value inside the type, I want to modify the Leg struct and then mark it as "complete" by moving the leg from where it is currently stored in `self._current_leg` to on the stack of completed legs in `self._completed_legs`. I then want to set the `_current_leg` value to the next leg in the `_expected_legs` stack. However, I get a mismatched type error on the line `self._completed_legs.push(leg)` in `Trip.dropoff()` because the stack expects a struct of type Leg and I am passing a `&mut Leg` type. I don't know how to move the value out of the `_current_leg` variable -- I seem to only be able to borrow the value.

The relevant code is at the bottom of this code block. Thanks for the help.

```
use std::collections;

pub struct Stack<T> {
    maxsize: usize,
    items: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Stack<T> {

    pub fn new(maxsize: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            maxsize,
            items: Vec::with_capacity(maxsize),
        }
    }
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.items.pop()
    }
    pub fn push(&mut self, item: T) -> bool {
        if self.items.len() == self.maxsize {
            return false;
        }
        self.items.push(item);
        return true;
    }
    pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
        self.items.len()
    }
    pub fn peek(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.items.last()
    }
}

pub struct Leg {
    // not important
    _trip_index: usize
}

impl Leg {
    fn dropoff(&mut self, time: i64) {

    }

    fn pickup(&mut self, time: i64) {

    }
}

pub struct Trip {
    _current_leg: Option<Leg>,
    _completed_legs: Stack<Leg>,
    _expected_legs: Stack<Leg>
}

impl Trip {

    fn dropoff(&mut self, time: i64) {
        let leg = self._current_leg.as_mut().unwrap();
        leg.dropoff(time);
        self._completed_legs.push(leg);
        self._current_leg = self._expected_legs.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `self._current_leg` is of type `Option<Leg>` but you cannot own it, because it is part of `self`. Basically is as if you had an `&mut Option<Leg>`. You cannot call `unwrap()`, as `unwrap()` takes ownership of the `Option`.

You solved this calling `as_mut()` but that converts your `&mut Option<Leg>` into a `Option<&mut Leg>`: now you own the `Option` but it does not contain the value, just a reference, so you still don't own the `Leg` itself.

What you need is [`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```
pub fn take(&mut self) -> Option<T>
```

It will replace the given value with `None` and return the previous value. Something like this will work in you code:

```
let mut leg = self._current_leg.take().unwrap();
```